# contentDescrption is not working using react-native-fbsdk

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I used the react-native for sharing i wrote like in mycode

```
   const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
const {
  LoginButton,
  ShareDialog,
} = FBSDK;

class HelloFacebook extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const shareLinkContent = {
      contentType: 'link',
      contentUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com',
      contentDescription: 'Wow, check out this great site!',
    };

    this.state = {
      shareLinkContent: shareLinkContent,
    };
  }

  shareLinkWithShareDialog() {
    var tmp = this;
    ShareDialog.canShow(this.state.shareLinkContent).then(
      function(canShow) {
        if (canShow) {
          return ShareDialog.show(tmp.state.shareLinkContent);
        }
      }
    ).then(
      function(result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          alert('Share cancelled');
        } else {
          alert('Share success with postId: '
            + result.postId);
        }
      },
      function(error) {
        alert('Share fail with error: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    alert("render")
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <LoginButton />
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.share}
          onPress={this.shareLinkWithShareDialog.bind(this)}>
          <Text style={styles.shareText}>Share link with ShareDialog</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  shareText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    margin: 10,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloFacebook', () => HelloFacebook);
```

But here the output which i got only the link which i want to share,i Didn't get any Description which i want to share
**What i need is :**
I want to share both contentDescription and contentUrl, so any one please give me the suggestions is there any thing wrong in my code, Any help much appreciated

Comment: Hey, try this sample project https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/tree/9b95c21002e4f5ad1c974a7d37e3817dba814072/Sample. It worked fine for me.

Comment: @jickson in this he used only content url in that case it is working for me but  it is not working for description, i want description and contentUrl

Comment: I added contentDescription in that project. It worked for me

Comment: @Jickson same code as like above or did you made any changes

Comment: I just added this line 'contentDescription: 'Wow, check out this great site!'' to that project. No other change.

Comment: I'm getting this same problem. No matter what I do it only uses contentUrl unless I am running the iOS simulator and don't specify a ShareDialog mode, then it opens a browser looking correct but if I try to set a mode (even to browser) or run it on an actual device it doesn't use any of my other fields.

Comment: @RyanWilson It worked for me in Android device. Not sure about iOS implementation.

Comment: For me I have same problem in iOS devices